# Rotativa Display HTML header and footer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I have recently started using Rotativa and works excellently! Except for attempting to configure the headers and the footers of the `PDF` documents.

```
string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html \"{4}\" --footer-left \"{0} {1} - {2}\" --footer-center \"{3}\" --footer-right \"Page: [page]/[toPage]\" --footer-line --footer-font-size \"9\" --footer-spacing 6", "Billing Report", FromDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ToDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), customerData.Name, Url.Action("BillingRunHeader", "Report", new { area = "Admin" }, "http"));
var actionResult = new ViewAsPdf("_BillingRunPDF", GetBillingReport(UserFilterReport, ProductFilterReport, ProjectFilterReport, CustomerFilterReport.Where(x => x == customer).ToArray(), TypeFilterReport, ReportType, FromDate, ToDate, Billable, TaskId).ToList())
{
     PageSize = Size.A4,
     PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
     FileName = customerData.Name.Replace(" ","_") + "_Billing_Report_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".pdf",
     CustomSwitches = customSwitches
};
```

Above I have created a string format to replace certain placeholders with data. The `--header-html \"{4}\"` is pulled from a `View` template stored which contains a image for the header and this displays perfectly. The issue is that the footer does not display at all.

If I remove the `--header-html \"{4}\"` then the footer displays perfectly fine. Issue is I need both the header and footer being displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it only worked after leaving the header and footer with HTML.

```
return new ViewAsPdf
            {
                ViewName = "RptVistoriador",
                PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
                Model = lstVistoriadorRptViewModel.ToPagedList(1, lstVistoriadorRptViewModel.Count()),                    
                CustomSwitches = $"--footer-html \"{Url.Action("ReportHeader", "Vistoriador", new { area = "" }, "http")}\" --header-html \"{Url.Action("ReportHeader", "Vistoriador", new { area = "" }, "http")}\""
            };
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `model.ToPagedList`?